# HtmlAgilityPack and HtmlDecode

Tags: html-agility-pack

I am currently using HtmlAgilityPack with a console application to scrape a website. Since the html is encoded (it returns encoded characters like `&#039;`) I have to decode before I save the content to my database.

Is there a way to decode the returned html using HtmlAgilityPack without having to use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode? I want to avoid adding System.Web to my console application if possible.

Comment: Why won't you add System.Web? As it is a default .net library it should be available on any client machine anyway...

Comment: @chrfin: Wrong; it isn't in the Client Profile.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The Html Agility Pack is equiped with a utility class called `HtmlEntity`. It has a static method with the following signature:

```c#
/// <summary>
/// Replace known entities by characters.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">The source text.</param>
/// <returns>The result text.</returns>
public static string DeEntitize(string text)
```

It supports well-known entities (like `&nbsp;`) and encoded characters such as `&#039;` as well.

Answer (score 18):

Just adding my 2 cents: I've ran some performance tests using `StopWatch` class and found that `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` is about 15-20% **faster** than the `DeEntitize` method. Also `DeEntitize` has some bugs (see comments above).

So maybe referencing System.Web is not that bad after all.

If you're writing an app that already targets ".NET full" (opposed to ".NET Client Profile" - which is a lightweight version) - I'd go for referencing System.Web.

Comment: What "comments above"?

Answer (score 9):

Use [WebUtility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility(v=vs.110).aspx) that doesn't need any special reference.