# How to remove &#160; in XPath return string

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using xpath to get the rows inside a table on a web page, it works fine except that when there's text with a space like "Age 23" it is returned as `Age&#160;23`. How can I fix this?

Here's my sentence:

```
var rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[tr/th[contains(.,'Pos')] and tr/th='Player' and tr/th='Date of birth (age)' and not(tr/th='Latest call-up')]/tr").ToList();
```

I'm using C# in Visual Studio

Comment: Which language ? Environment ?

Comment: Added them to the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HtmlAgilityPack and HtmlDecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665488/htmlagilitypack-and-htmldecode)